# rxvt-unicode(urxvt-256colors) prints broken UTF-8 after OS update

Tags: utf-8, urxvt

I'm  using openSuSE Tumbleweed. After distribution update via `sudo zypper dup`, `rxvt-unicode` ( I'm using `urxvt-256color`) shows weird behavior. It printed sane UTF-8 chars (e.g. `ビール`) before updating, but it prints broken UTF-8 chars (like consecutive `æ¨`, etc.)

[image: it renders broken utf8]

I reinstalled urxvt but no effects occurred. Any informations is welcome.

My locale:

```bash
% locale
LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

urxvt version:

```bash
rxvt-unicode (urxvt) v9.30 - released: 2021-11-27
options: perl,xft,styles,combining,blink,iso14755,unicode3,encodings=eu+vn+jp+jp-ext+kr+zh+zh-ext,fade,transparent,tint,pixbuf,XIM,8bitctrls,frills,selectionscrolling,wheel,slipwheel,smart-resize,cursorBlink,pointerBlank,scrollbars=plain+rxvt+NeXT+xterm
```

my `.Xresources` profile:

```
rxvt*saveLines: 200
! do not scroll with output
URxvt*scrollTtyOutput: false

! scroll in relation to buffer (with mouse scroll or Shift+Page Up)
URxvt*scrollWithBuffer: true

! scroll back to the bottom on keypress
URxvt*scrollTtyKeypress: true

URxvt.font: xft:Berkeley Mono:pixelsize=18
URxvt.perl-ext-common: default,matcher,resize-font,fullscreen
URxvt.url-launcher: /usr/bin/xdg-open
URxvt.matcher.button: 1
URxvt.keysym.F11: perl:fullscreen:switch

! Kill some default key bindings such as Ctrl+Shift+...
URxvt.iso14755: false
URxvt.iso14755_52: false

! Fix font space
!URxvt*letterSpace: -1

!! Color Scheme and Opacity - gruvbox-dark https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox
URxvt.depth:                32
URxvt.color0:               [90]#282828
URxvt.color1:               [90]#cc241d
URxvt.color2:               [90]#98971a
URxvt.color3:               [90]#d79921
URxvt.color4:               [90]#458588
URxvt.color5:               [90]#b16286
URxvt.color6:               [90]#689d6a
URxvt.color7:               [90]#a89984
URxvt.color8:               [90]#928374
URxvt.color9:               [90]#fb4934
URxvt.color10:              [90]#b8bb26
URxvt.color11:              [90]#fabd2f
URxvt.color12:              [90]#83a598
URxvt.color13:              [90]#d3869b
URxvt.color14:              [90]#8ec07c
URxvt.color15:              [90]#ebdbb2
URxvt.foreground:           [90]#ebdbb2
URxvt.background:           [90]#282828
URxvt.colorIT:              [90]#8ec07c
URxvt.colorBD:              [90]#d5c4a1
URxvt.colorUL:              [90]#83a598
URxvt.scrollColor:          [90]#504945
!URxvt.troughColor:          [90]#3C3836

emacs.FontBackend: xft
```

openSuSE:

```bash
% cat /etc/os-release
NAME="openSUSE Tumbleweed"
# VERSION="20231008"
ID="opensuse-tumbleweed"
ID_LIKE="opensuse suse"
VERSION_ID="20231008"
PRETTY_NAME="openSUSE Tumbleweed"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:opensuse:tumbleweed:20231008"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.opensuse.org"
SUPPORT_URL="https://bugs.opensuse.org"
HOME_URL="https://www.opensuse.org"
DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://en.opensuse.org/Portal:Tumbleweed"
LOGO="distributor-logo-Tumbleweed"
```

Comment: Check `locale -a` to see if such locale is installed (and if it had a rename, e.g. losing the hyphen) and do also `sudo locale` to check if root has now unexpected values

Comment: `locale -a` showed me `ja_JP.utf8`. So Do I have to use `ja_JP.utf8`  as `LANG`?

Comment: Additional info: I tried other terminal emulators. Xterms printed UTF-8 well. GNOME Terminal does too.

Comment: This may related. https://www.mail-archive.com/rxvt-unicode@lists.schmorp.de/msg02243.html

Answer (score 0):

I removed perl extension in `.Xresources` and worked.

from:

```
URxvt.perl-ext-common: default,matcher,resize-font,fullscreen
```

to:

```
URxvt.perl-ext-common:
```

There may be bug in Perl v5.38.0: https://www.mail-archive.com/rxvt-unicode@lists.schmorp.de/msg02243.html